# In Javafx 8, how can I get the correct screen position of a 3d Node?

Tags: java, 3d, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently working on a 3d visualisation project using javafx 8.

As having too many points is slow when rotating the camera around, I decided to hide those points(3d boxes in my case) not displayed on the scene.

The problem is when I call box.localToScreen(0, 0, 0), the coordinates seems not correct some times. e.g, sometimes the point is still displayed on the screen, but its coordinates returned by localToScreen(0, 0, 0) can be negative. Have I missed something? or have I misused this method?

Here are some codes I have:

```
// where I build these boxes from points
for (point p : mergedList) {
    Box pointBox = new Box(length, width, height);

    boxList.add(pointBox);
    pointBox.setTranslateX(p.getX());
    pointBox.setTranslateY(p.getY());
    pointBox.setTranslateZ(p.getZ());

...

// where I call localToScreen to get its coordinates
for (Box b : boxList) {
    Point2D p = b.localToScreen(0, 0, 0); // I have also tried b.localToScreen(b.getTranslateX(), b.getTranslateY(), b.getTranslateZ())
    double x = p.getX(), y = p.getY();
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for solution to some of the localToScreen and screenToLocal issues. 
For your case, if you are using multiple monitors, only the primary monitor provides you positive coordinates. The secondary monitor will give you negative coordinates.
Have you try localToScene instead of localToScreen ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried localToScene, which didn't work. Now we have switched to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the localToScreen method transforms the "provided" point by the "calling" objects point.

Use getLocalToSceneTransform() ... 
this is your "world-Matrix", and hold all your transformation info. Rotations, scale, etc..
your position values are {Tx, Ty, Tz} so plug those into a Point3D and you have your position in SceneSpace (mostly accurate)

Another dirty option to "hide" the Boxes, is to set it's Cullface to Front. This will reduce some of the performance issues, since it does not need to be rendered, but leads to other potential problems with Mouse Picking and such.

I recently posted a video of 32k+ cubes being rendered, and I noticed 0 performance issues,
(the video encoding was not that great it's blurry in the beginning) 
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6yVVBJoNkY)

Hope it helps!